# Add async keyword to Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, asynchronous

The following gives me an 8 second page load

```
    $temp_facebook_comments = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=" . $comment_page);
$facebook_comments = json_decode($temp_facebook_comments);
$facebook_comments_array = array();
if(isset($facebook_comments->{$comment_page}->comments->data))
```

I'm looking for a way to add an async keyword to defer facebook load.

Comment: `async` is used in client-side script embedding to not have to loading of an external JavaScript resource block loading of the rest of the page. You can not just transfer that to PHP on the server side. There is no asynchrony for a single PHP script run on a web server to deliver a web page – that whole concept does not work there. You can either load the data in a second request (AJAX), or you’d have to set up some sort of background process that pulls the data independently of the current script, and have the latter only read the response from the latest previous run of that background task.

Comment: Thanks for the advice CBroe - I've gone with AJAX solution which loads Facebook script after initial page load and it works well.